# Trigonometric equation with generalized solution

Tags: trigonometry

The equation

$$\cot A -  \tan A=2$$
Find the generalized form of $A$

I got the answer and the answer came 
$$\tan A=(2^{1/2})-1 \text{ and } -2^{1/2}-1$$

Now how to write the generalized form j here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cot A-\tan A=\frac{\cos^2A-\sin^2A}{\sin A\cos A}=2\cot2A$$

$$\implies2\cot2A=2\iff \tan2A=1\implies2A=n\pi+\frac\pi4$$ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be $\arctan(2^{1/2}-1)+k\pi$ and $\arctan(-2^{1/2}-1)+k\pi$, $k\in\Bbb{Z}$.  But it becomes simpler if you calculate $\tan 2A$ first.